# How to know if a DB transaction is successfully committed in case of timeout?

Tags: transaction, auto-commit

Out of curiosity:

For example, I issue `commit` at the end of a transaction and wait for the response from the database. If for some reason, the waiting times out, how can I know if this transaction has been successfully committed and thus made durable by the DB?

I supposed 3 possible reasons for the timeout:

- The commit command is not delivered to the database.
- The commit command is well delivered to the database but for some reason not processed by the DB and DB is just stuck there.
- The commit command is well delivered to the database and processed by the DB, but for some reason, the response from the database cannot be delivered to my client application.

Comment: I think it depends on database management system you are using. AFAIK, all transactions are registered and can be queried (e.g. sp_who2 in SQL Server to see SPIDs).

Comment: Look at [Database transactions - How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466632/database-transactions-how-do-they-work).